# WebSocket error when using Playwright on GitLab CI

Tags: jestjs, gitlab-ci, playwright

I am using Playwright with Jest and jest-playwright-preset and trying to get my tests to run in GitLab CI.

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
ui_test:
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test:ui
```

When I run this locally on my Windows machine everything works fine. However if I try to run in GitLab CI I get the following error:

```
 2020-06-26T21:01:39.770Z pw:api => chromium.launchServer started
 2020-06-26T21:01:39.786Z pw:api <= chromium.launchServer succeeded
 2020-06-26T21:01:40.182Z pw:api => chromium.connect started
 2020-06-26T21:01:40.217Z pw:api <= chromium.connect failed
 FAIL browser: chromium ./test.js
   ● Test suite failed to run
     WebSocket error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:38267
     ================== chromium.connect logs ==================
     <ws connecting> ws://127.0.0.1:38267/b32ed779b7c87222e0b2b6aa117b0c79
     <ws connect error> ws://127.0.0.1:38267/b32ed779b7c87222e0b2b6aa117b0c79 connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:38267
     <ws disconnected> ws://127.0.0.1:38267/b32ed779b7c87222e0b2b6aa117b0c79
     ============================================================
     Note: use DEBUG=pw:api environment variable and rerun to capture Playwright logs.
       at WebSocket.<anonymous> (node_modules/playwright/lib/transport.js:119:24)
       at WebSocket.onError (node_modules/playwright/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:128:16)
       at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/playwright/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:568:15)
```

EDIT: This has nothing to do with Jest. The same problem will arise when only using Playwright and using the node image instead of the Playwright image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `node:latest` does not have the appropriate system dependencies to run the browsers. You can use the [Playwright docker image](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/docs/docker/Dockerfile.bionic).

```
ui-test:
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:bionic
  script:
    - npm install # this should install playwright
    - npm run test:ui
```

(Edited to reflect the official docker image)